# wget log failed download url using bash function

Tags: wget

I was using below command to download list of urls

```
function() { wget "$(echo "$1" | some command)"; }
cat url |  xargs -I {} bash -c 'function "{}"'
```

How can i log failed download url?
Tried

```
wget -a log
```

But not working

Comment: Please explain why are you not using `-i` option of `wget`

Comment: -i requires making temp file containing url.

Comment: not it does not, use `-` to inform `wget` to use standard input as file. From [`wget` manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) **-i** _file_  Read URLs from a local or external _file_. If - is specified as _file_, URLs are read from the standard input.

Comment: Also tried --rejected-log=log but not working. failed downloads were not being logged